# Getting file path within dos batch file within for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, dos

I'm trying to create a batch file that will go into a directory and look for log files and then search the log files to see if the word "ERROR:" is in the start of a line.  That part I have figured out.  My issue now is trying to create a display row to show what directory i'm in with *.log after it.

For example

-------c:\temp*.log-----------------

--c:\temp\temp1.log

--c:\temp\temp2.log

ERROR: Temp error

-------c:\temp\subdir*.log-----------------

--c:\temp\subdir\temp3.log

ERROR: This is an error

--c:\temp\subdir\temp4.log

This is the code i'm currently using

```
Set _OutFile=c:\temp\check_error.txt
If Exist "%_OutFile%" Del "%_OutFile%"
For /F "Tokens=* Delims=" %%I In ('Dir /b "c:\temp\*.log"') Do (
(Echo.
 Echo.---------- %%~I
 )>>"%_OutFile%"
Findstr /B /C:"ERROR:"  "%%I">>"%_OutFile%"
)
```

This will only produce

---------- TempData.log

It doesn't show the main path or the files path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Echo.---------- %%~I
```

to this:

```
Echo.---------- %%~fI
```

Comment: aphoria,  Thank you that added the full path.  How can I get the root directory that I'm currently in?

Comment: The `%CD%` environment variable will return the current directory. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot.  Is there a way to uppercase %%~fI?   For this approach I know there are only two directories so I'm doing them separately.  I think eventually I will need to have a for loop within a for loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, in batch there is not an easy way to convert to upper or lower case. You can find a few options at http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_convertcase.php, but it may be more trouble than it's worth.